# Does anyone know browser emulators?

Tags: testing, browser, selenium, cross-platform, simulation

Over 2 years I tested web application with help [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) framework. I know the best design is testing on VM.

The only one downside of this - it's very slow testing. Why?

- browser only gets so much memory, if you will run several instances.
- site coud be very slow.
- connections can be very slow.

Would be great if there was a framework that emulated the browser (engine/core) correctly and can provide some results (api) for surf on the page.

I don't mean to simulate just on the one browser with different version (like IE). I mean to simulate for all browsers with very popular and newest version.

Does anyone know a framework/tool that can do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for example.

From their page:

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit with JavaScript API. It has fast and
>   native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector,
>   JSON, Canvas, and SVG.

You can use it in combination with [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) (as well as several other frameworks) for testing.

However the selection of available engines is limited to WebKit. I doubt that Selenium will be easy to replace. By the way it looks like Selenium [will probably become a W3C standard](https://twitter.com/AutomatedTester/status/222705127792984064) over the next years.

Comment: This is a great option, and there's even a [Selenium WebDriver interface for PhantomJS](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) being developed.

Comment: hmm, it's something new. Thank you @kostja for you advice. I'll investigate this framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run Selenium with Xvfb - I use it to execute test on remote server and it is going very well.